# Rotating an NSButton not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, caanimation

I have the code to animate diagonally down.

```
CABasicAnimation *rightAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
[rightAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:160]];
[rightAnimation setBeginTime:0.0];
[rightAnimation setDuration:0.4];


CABasicAnimation *fall = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
[fall setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-20]];
[fall setBeginTime:0.1];
[fall setDuration:0.3];

//DOESN'T WORK
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.z"];
[rotate setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_RADIANS(30)]];
[rotate setBeginTime:0.0];
[rotate setDuration:0.4];

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[group setDuration:0.4];
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rightAnimation, fall, rotate, nil]];

[submitButton.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:nil];
```

which works perfectly apart from I would also like for the button to rotate 30 degrees. But for some weird reason, this does not happen, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.z"];
```

to this:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen "DEGREES_RADIANS," I believe that you may in fact mean "degreesToRadians." If so, the following code should suffice:

```
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:degreesToRadians(30)];
```